# How to call a task in a helper?

Tags: routes, symfony-1.4, task

I want to create a button in my application to call a task.

How can I do this with a `link_to()` in my template for example ?

In `routing.yml` it is possible to create a route to call the task ?

Answer (score 2):

A task can't be launched from a web environment. The goal of a task is to run in command line. You can't achieve what you want to do *like* you want to do.

You should take a look at message queue soft for that:

- on an action (a link for example), add an item into the queue
- each time an item is added to a queue, it launch an action (can be a task for example)

In your case, your item will tell to the queue manager to launch a particular task.

There are a lot of differents message queue soft around [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/), Redis, [Bernard](https://github.com/henrikbjorn/Bernard), [AMPQ](http://amqp.org/), etc ..

But you can also *built* your own using a MySQL database (for example):

- create a database called `todo` (with an id, a flag, a task name, a field for parameters)
- on an action (a link for example), add an item to this table (with all informations)
- create a `todoTask` that will:

  - fetch items from this table
  - mark them as processed
  - and launch the task described inside the row (with parameters, etc ..) for each item

Comment: Finally, I think that the easiest way is to rewrite the task in the `action.class.php` and to call it then, because your solution is complicated to just do what I want

Comment: Instead of duplicate the code, you can create a lib that will be used by the task **and** the action.